# Manipualte json with Js

Tags: javascript, json, data-manipulation

I have a json as below. You can see a tree view of [same here](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=617329023b5bf648e1dd0d057dbd1ccd).

```
{

  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "property1": {
          "href": "http://www.somesite.com/neatobambino/2015/12/29/Little-Girl-Uses-Dogs-Tail-as-a-Paintbrush/",
          "text": "Little Girl Uses Dog's Tail as a Paintbrush"
        },
        "property5": {
          "alt": "",
          "src": "",
          "text": ""
        },
        "index": 1,
        "url": "http://www.somesite.com/"
      },                   

      {
        "property1": {
          "href": "http://www.somesite.com/2015/09/11/20-Alternative-Housing-Solutions-for-the-Homeless/",
          "text": "20 Alternative Housing Solutions for the Homeless"
        },
        "property5": [
          {
            "alt": "",
            "src": "http://www.somesite.com/page/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "alt": "",
            "src": "http://www.somesite.com/page/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=",
            "text": ""
          }
        ],
        "index": 2500,
        "url": "http://www.somesite.com/page/84"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you you see the result is two level inside. Inside `results`, we again have `collection1`. The whole json is inside an object `data`. How can I move whole data in `collection1` directly to `results`?

Some thing like.

```
var data.results = data.results.collections;
```

Can you do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes that should work, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gt7dwypf/)

```
obj.results = obj.results.collection1;
console.log( obj );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new object and try to assign

```
var newData = {
"results": data.results.collections;
}
```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is a new variable where you have the store the values that you want, in this case you want to store the values data.results.collection1 in a variable named results, so:

```
var results = data.results.collection1;
```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery , you can use 
var obj=$.extend({},data.results.collection1)

$.extend makes deep copy so obj will be independent object.

If you are using native JS,then use

var obj=Object.create(data.results.collection1)
or
var copy = Object.assign({}, data.results.collection1); // this is ES6 specific

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.